# wpf app invisible remotely (via radmin)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've built a little WPF utility that watches a serialport and visualises monitoring information with WPF. It works fine, but a colleague just tried using it from another machine via radmin and my app is completely invisible! if you're at the machine you see it, if you view it via radmin you see the same screen but no app. Instead you see the app behind it (in this case windows explorer), but can't click on anything in the space where my app is.

Has anyone else come across this before??

Comment: I'm using radmin too, and I never encountered that issue with WPF apps... check out Brian's answer, it seems promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the framework and it was already 3.5 SP1.
It's ok via RDP, so my colleague is happy. It just seems to be radmin, which I'd never used before and don't see the need for.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to upgrade to .NET 3.5 SP1.

> On .Net Framework 3.5 SP1
>
> We now remote as bitmaps in ALL cases.
>   The reason is that WPF 3.5 SP1 now
>   uses a new graphics DLL (wpfgfx.dll)
>   and certain changes could not be made
>   to Vista’s existing graphics DLL
>   (milcore.dll) that is also used by
>   DWM. Although this could be seen a
>   regression at first, depending on the
>   complexity of the application scene
>   (e.g. very rich scenes) this can
>   actually improve performance in
>   certain scenarios . Also, connections
>   with reasonably high bandwidth and
>   scenarios that don’t involve a lot of
>   animation or 3D, for instance, tend to
>   remote just fine via bitmaps.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/jgoldb/archive/2008/05/15/what-s-new-for-performance-in-wpf-in-net-3-5-sp1.aspx)